# Determine whether Logic Board has actually been replaced

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, logicboard

I recently had the Logic Board in my Retina MBP 15″ 2012 replaced under a warranty extension program and Apple paid for it. I've reinstalled OS X several times and feel things aren't running properly. Also, I also couldn't find a way to merge my Time Machine old backups with new one.

The problem I have is confirming that I actually got a new board installed. I have not found a way to confirm this. My Mac help isn't helpful and Google is even less helpful. Why is it so hard to confirm that new hardware is really installed after this repair?

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the serial number on the bottom of the laptop casing to the serial number shown in System Report by going to Apple Menu -> About This Mac. When I worked at Apple, it was known that replacement logic boards would carry the new SN (naturally) and that cases from the old SN would link to the new one.

The serial on the laptop itself is the original SN it shipped with (unless the bottom case has also been replaced) and can be found in very small print near the display hinge. On the Mac, check for an SN that diverges or is not present, as that indicates repair.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a system report hanging around from before the repair?  If so, you could compare things like the AirPort MAC address (or any info cached on your router), any Thunderbolt specific addresses that appear.

You could use something like [this](http://www.chipmunk.nl/klantenservice/applemodel.html) to see if the logic board has a newer manufacture date?

Comment: Hey thanks. Not likely to have a report handy but I'll look. As for this tool, it give less info than the System Report applet.

Comment: Ah yes, the problem, unfortunately is that the SN of your new logic board has been made to match that of your Mac.   Any luck with the MAC address of the wireless/Ethernet?

Comment: AirPort hardware is separate than the logic board. The ethernet MAC address would be something that changes on a logic board replacement though but that model doesn't have an ethernet port. Good thought on the thunderbolt or HDMI serializations though. Perhaps that would be enough to establish a change.

Answer (score 0):

Because of an repair with an old macbook pro (2007) the repair service *forgot to set the serial number* of the new motherboard.

Because of this I had *several problems with iCloud*. For letting to correct this problem by this SP about 1800km/1118miles away I would have to drive/fly this long way. Therefore I searched if I could fix this problem myself because a different SP would cost perhaps. Then I found an image you can burn on CD/DVD (or anything else from what the macbook can boot). Then with this image **anyone can set the serial number** ***once***. Perhaps then no one can change the serial number again but I do not know this for sure.

For more information: *http://rogersm.net/icloud-problems-mountain-lion-serial-number*

But it seems the *AASP is advised to change the serial number* and not to set the *old serial number*. It is sad you *can not be really sure* the new motherboard does not have the bug of the early systems and perhaps the motherboard has been produced with this bug. But I trust Apple they sent a fixed new motherboard to the SP or AASP.

That is why it is sadly wrong that in info under mac os x you can get the not falsified serial number.

*What I did not look:* If you open you Mac(book) completely perhaps on motherboard is a number printed which says when and where the motherboard has been produced (as you can see in model number of an iOS device). I did not see if mac os x displays the model number of the motherboard or any device. **But I do not recommend** it if you have any guaranty yet else you might loose this guaranty by opening the Mac.

**=> It is therefore absolutely wrong to trust a MAC address or motherboard serial number is unique. Theoretically a MAC address shall be unique but practically on some network card or usb network devices one may change the MAC address.**
*I know this because I am a bit informed about network security.*

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily tell from software that you have a new board unless the technician failed to properly deserialize the part that was "allegedly" put in.  However, the Time Machine change makes me conclude you have a new board.

You could try dumping the hardware identity from the Time Machine backup directory:

```
xattr -p com.apple.backupd.BackupMachineAddress /Volumes/yourBackupDrive/Backups.backupdb/yourMacName
```

Since you paid for the repair, Apple should walk you though re-joining the Time Machine over the phone or via internet chat for free post repair.

Did you have it serviced via mail in or at an authorized service provider or at a genius bar? The steps to get repair details can change a little - but you could start by calling AppleCare and asking them to read the technician notes that were left by the repair tech. There should be time stamps when it started repair - possibly a list of parts used, probably some test results they ran, etc... Usually a logic board has it's own internal serialization, but you need to open the hardware to see that or have knowledge of revisions on the boards. If the board was improved after it was made or someone checked the serial number on the board that was fitted in the factory initially, you could know that the one in there wasn't original.

Unless you took a photo of the board that was installed or marked it before the repair, it's unlikely you can differentiate things from software.

Basically, the evidence you can gather is mostly circumstantial unless you are in the forensics trade or work on machines as a trained repair technician that works on that model routinely.

Comment: Also - I jest with the "allegedly" - there's absolutely no incentive for an employee to not replace the board. Apple collects each bad board so the technician would then have to send back the same part or another part - both of which is likely to get caught and get them and their immediate employer extra attention by Apple. They take their repair programs very seriously and have high standards for certified technicians. Without Apple's certification, you're an out of work tech.